# Sum across columns based on 3 criteria

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to get a Sumif working across multiple rows.

For example, say my data source is below:

```
    A     B     C
1   1    10    11
2   2     9    12
3   3     8    13
4   4     7    14
5   5     6    58
```

I want to sum from Columns A to C, in row 3. Output would be 24.
Ideally my criteria for the Horizontal Start, Horizontal End and Vertical would all be referenced in different cells which can be updated to get a new result depending on the criteria.

Is this possible so that the criteria cells can be updated and the formula will update accordingly?

Comment: yes, it can. what you have try?

Comment: If that ends up in a rectangle, then you could use something like `=SUM(INDEX([gets upper left corner]):INDEX([gets lower right corner]))`. like `=SUM(A2:INDEX(A:C,4,2))` would sum the range `A2:B4`. Hope that helps a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a SUMIF, and betweem the logical criteria, simply use 3 criterias by seperating each with "&"'. This says that excel will sum if a happens, and b and c.